# How to combine two regex in one when we format number to US format

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I want to combine two regexes in one, but I don't know how to do it in my case.
So, I want to do next thing: function that format number to US-format, simply adding commas for 1000, like ***1,000*** and so on. (I know about `toLocaleString('en-US')` and `Intl.NumberFormat.prototype.format` but these are unsuitable for my case).
For do it using regex I tried this expression: `/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g` and it works well, but ***only*** if our number contains ***dot*** (e.g. `1000.23`), but if there is *no dot*, the current regex won't work.
(*Proof:* https://regex101.com/r/93O0gJ/1)

There is another regex that I have to make my function work properly: `/\d(?=(\d{3})+$)/g` but it works properly only when we have ***no dot's at all***. If we have dots, it will replace the *float or fractional part* with commas, and it is not a correct behaviour for my requirements. (*My number would be like "1000.12,345,678" for number 1000.12345678*). But without dots in number everything works well.
(Proof: https://regex101.com/r/BHikK7/1)

So, for my case I create function that checks:
if ***number*** has dots, I use the 1st regex, if doesn't, I use 2nd:

```
const formatNumberToUSFormat = (numberToFormat: number):string => {
  const stringNumber = numberToFormat.toString()

  return stringNumber.match(/\./g) ?
    stringNumber.replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,') : 
    stringNumber.replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$&,')
}
```

My main question — how to combine two regex in one in my case and by that avoid unnecessary checks for dots and so on.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `(\d)(\d{3})(\.\d+)?` [here](https://regex101.com/r/swu2DG/1).

Comment: You can use `|` in Regex it functions as a boolean OR

Comment: Are you expecting digits of variable length?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness does not work for big numbers:
https://regex101.com/r/2qjIYu/1

Comment: Yeah, hence why I asked if you are expecting digits of variable length.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness for 100 billion as maximum, I guess, it would be great.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness
Is it possible?

Comment: It's certainly possible but its considerably tricky, because you have to count three digits counting from right to left. Perhaps @Wiktor has a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Since there is only (?=...) 'followed by' expression and no 'preceded by' - you can reverse the string in order to properly use 'followed by' like this:

```js
const num = '1234567890.12345';
const result = [...[...num] // destructing the string
  .reverse().join('') // reversing the original string
  .replace(/(?:\d+\.)?(\d{3}(?=\d))/g,'$&,')]
  .reverse().join(''); // reversing the result back to normal
console.log(result);
```

But this approach is faaar from optimal!
Do not use it if you have a lot of data to process!

Answer (score 1):

Regexp from hell, but it works )))

```
const num = '1234567890.123456';
const result  = num.replace(new RegExp('\\B(?=(\\d{3})+'+(~num.indexOf('.')?'\\.':'$')+')','g'),',');

console.log(result);
```

Original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46371080/6776408

Answer (score 0):

Check on the next regex `(?:(?<=^|[^\d.])(\d{1,3})(?=(?:\d{3})+(?:\D|$))|\G)(\d{3})`.

To try the regex online and get an explanation, please click [here](https://regex101.com/r/xfQtyA/3).